# Background Image validation in QTP

Tags: background-image, qtp, ui-automation

I am have a `Div` on the home page and I need to compare its background image with an image whose path I would provide at run-time.

I am looking to incorporate a .dll file of image comparison but would be great any other better option available.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Descriptive Programming approach to validate BG images.

Comment: could you pls explain it a bit

Comment: you can use DP or image check point. Also there is one free library available, check this [link] http://knowledgeinbox.com/downloads/general/screen-capture-and-comparison-com-api/